# Failing distribution checksum during FreeBSD automated install (bsdinstall)

Tags: freebsd, system-installation, bsdinstall

I'm using the following `installerconfig` to automate the installation of FreeBSD (13.2-RELEASE):

```
export PARTITIONS=DEFAULT
export DISTRIBUTIONS="kernel.txz base.txz"
export HOSTNAME=freebsd
export BSDINSTALL_DISTSITE="https://download.freebsd.org/releases/amd64/13.2-RELEASE"
export INTERFACES=vtnet0
export nonInteractive="YES"

dhclient $INTERFACES

#!/bin/sh
sysrc ifconfig_DEFAULT=DHCP
sysrc sshd_enable=YES
```

This invariably results in a checksum mismatch ("The checksum for kernel.txz does not match..."). I've verified that the checksums `/usr/freebsd-dist/MANIFEST` on the installer image **do** match the checksums of the files contained in `$BSDINSTALL_DISTSITE`.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was [a bug](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=273148) introduced last year in commit [1f7746d81f](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/commit/?id=1f7746d81f53447ac15cc99395bb714d4dd0a4da). That commit replaced:

```
exec 3>&1
export BSDINSTALL_DISTDIR=$(`dirname $0`/fetchmissingdists 2>&1 1>&3)
FETCH_RESULT=$?
exec 3>&-

[ $FETCH_RESULT -ne 0 ] && error "Could not fetch remote distributions"
```

With:

```
(
  exec 3>&1
  export BSDINSTALL_DISTDIR=$(`dirname $0`/fetchmissingdists 2>&1 1>&3)
  FETCH_RESULT=$?
  exec 3>&-
  return $FETCH_RESULT
) || error "Could not fetch remote distributions"
```

The replacement suffers from [BASH FAQ 024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

---

I have reverted the patch in my local project and I am now able to perform completely automated installs.